# Best way of communicating with web service in multi-form environment

Tags: c#, winforms, wcf, wif

The scenario is that we have a winforms application that has on the main form references to some webservices that are secured via WCF and an STS/WIF.

The credential management is handled on this main form, but we have a lot of sub forms and user controls etc that need access to these webservices.

At the moment the webservices are instantiated and then called at the point of need, but now they are secured via WCF, really we only need the references to them on the main form, otherwise we'll need to pass the credentials between forms to re-create the security - which evades the point of handling the security once.

What would you consider to be the best way to pass a reference to the services on the parent (main) form to these other forms and controls?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Pass the web service object in constructor of the other forms like so

  var childForm = new ChildForm(theServiceObject);
- Put it in some static single ton and every form can get it from there like so

  var theServiceObject = ServiceInstance.Get();
- Use IOC container and have the other forms get the service via property, method or constructor injection after the main form has done the credential verification